# why (0x80000000 +0x80000000) >>31 output are different?

Tags: c

Why the output between `main()` and `func()` are different?
I want to get the sign bit with bitwise operation and '+'operation,
so I use this statement: `(x >> 31) & 0x1` to determine whether the sign bit is `1`, and its worked well in the past, but today I meet this problem, why the output are different?

```
  #include <stdio.h>
    int func(int x)
    {
    printf("func:\n");

int minint = 0x1 << 31;
int addx = x + minint;

printf("x = %.8x\n", x);
printf("x + minint = %.8x\n",addx);
printf("right shift: %.8x\n",addx >> 31);
}
```

output:

```
func:
x = 80000000
x + minint = 00000000
right shift: ffffffff
```

---

```
int main()
{
    printf("main:\n");
int x = 0x80000000;
int minint = 0x1 << 31;
int addx = x + minint;
printf("x = %.8x\n", x);
printf("x + minint = %.8x\n",addx);
printf("right shift: %.8x\n",addx >> 31);
func(0x80000000);
return 0;
}
```

output:

```
main:
x = 80000000
x + minint = 00000000
right shift: 00000000
```

Comment: Shifting into (or out of) the sign bit (bit 31 of a 32-bit integer) is undefined behaviour. Anything can happen. Maybe - just maybe - in your case, the compiler is doing the `main` calculation at compile time (because it can) but leaving the `func` calculation to run time.

Comment: On my set up I get the same output. What if you change all the `int`s to `long`s (assuming `long` is wider than `int` on your system) and instead of `%.8x` you use `%.8lx`?

Comment: Also, the `%x` format is for **unsigned** types.

Comment: oh my complier is gcc on windows10, maybe this problem is from different complier?

Comment: It is *undefined* behaviour. So the result may differ with the phase of the moon. It not the compiler which is a problem, but the code.

Comment: so if I want to get the sign bit, how to get the correct answer?

Comment: Start with `0x1u << 31`. That's well-defined and upon assignment to int, you end up with an unsigned to signed conversion which is implementation-defined (meaning compiler-specific, rather than undefined behavior meaning bug). Right-shifting a negative int is also implementation-defined, it could result in either arithmetic or logical shift. As you might realize by now, shifting signed integers in C is not a brilliant idea in general.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem here. See https://godbolt.org/z/h4avd9bqs

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain what you want to achieve in the end. What do you mean with "I want to get the sign bit". One way to get the sign in a portable way is `sign = (x < 0) ? 1 : 0;` (The compiler will do the optimization.)

Comment: @Bodo This is also portable (but ugly): `#define SHIFT (CHAR_BIT*sizeof(int)-1)` ... `_Bool sign = x & (1u << SHIFT)`.

Comment: @Lundin My main point is that it is not necessary to use bit shifting in the C source. With a decent optimizing compiler, readable C code may result in the same machine code. See e.g. https://godbolt.org/z/hMo5hKqMb

Comment: @Castle What's the reason for the restriction in the requirement "I want to get the sign bit *with bitwise operation and '+'operation*"? Look at the generated code:  http://godbolt.org/z/hMo5hKqMb You can choose different compilers. Most compilers produce the same assembly code for the two functions.